# import touchstone file into ltspice

Tags: ltspice, s-parameters, import

Does anyone know how to import Sparameter (touchstone) files into ltSpice and how to use them?
I have downloaded s3p format file, but I don't know how to use it. I cant find any information in the Internet.

Thank you

Comment: If the file is text, post a copy

Comment: You seem to need help with search skills more than touchstone https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235003/convert-a-s2p-file-to-spice-model  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Sparameter+(touchstone)+files+into+ltSpice&t=brave&ia=web

Comment: Where did you read that LTSpice has the capability to import a Touchstone file?